# ArcGIS Server - Secured Services

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, security, arcgis-soap-api

Is there any way to tell, via the SOAP or REST APIs, if an ArcGIS Server map service requires an authenticated user?

I have set an application to use a token service for accessing secured map services, but I am trying to find if there is a quick way to tell whether or not the service requires a user to be logged-in.

Answer (score 1):

The `/arcgis/rest/info?f=pjson` endpoint will have an `authInfo` property with this information:

Example:
http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/info?f=pjson

```
{
 "currentVersion": 10.3,
 "fullVersion": "10.3.0",
 "soapUrl": "http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services",
 "secureSoapUrl": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services",
 "authInfo": {
  "isTokenBasedSecurity": true,
  "tokenServicesUrl": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/tokens/",
  "shortLivedTokenValidity": 60
 }
}
```